# I'm having trouble sending leads from LinkedIn with Zapier to Slate CRM

Tags: crm, zapier, slate

I am trying to send LinkedIn leads from LinkedIn via Webhooks by Zapier to [Slate](https://technolutions.com/) but every time I test successfully from Zapier I get an error in Slate.

Here is the error I am getting on the Slate side:

[zapier data impor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UthWp.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnTvv.png)

[data that is coming through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCKrQ.png)

Here is how my Zap is set up: [zapier screenshot/Webhook settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKI86.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I've been having issues trying to integrate LinkedIn and Slate with Zapier, but I think I see your problem. You need to change your Payload Type from 'Form' to 'XML'.

If you're able to get the data to load into Slate, please share your Source Format XML definition.